# Ozsvath-Szabo orientation convention for Seifert fibred spaces

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, heegaard-floer-homology

I am confused by the orientation convention that Ozsvath and Szabo use in [On Heegaard Floer homology and Seifert Fibered Surgeries](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0301026.pdf) and would appreciate if someone clarifies this for me. On page 15 there is a

**Definition 3.1** Suppose that $\Gamma$ is a weighted tree which has either negative-definite
or negative-semi-definite intersection form. Then, we say that the induced
orientation $-\partial W(\Gamma)$ is a positive Seifert orientation.

I am confused by the use of "induced orientation" together with a minus sign after it. It seems that there is a double negation going on. Is that true? More precisely, does this definition say:

Let $Y$ be a Seifert fibred space that bounds a positive definite 4-manifold obtained by plumbing, Then $Y$ has positive Seifert orientation. If $Y$ is a Seifert fibred space that bounds a negative definite 4-manifold obtained by plumbing, Then $Y$ has negative Seifert orientation. (Can have both.) Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it appears to say so. Is this not consistent with their results?

Comment: @MarcoGolla: No, I don't know if it is inconsistent or not. I just wanted to make sure I understand this correctly. The double negation is what confuses me and makes me unsure whether I understand it correctly.